# Is there any possibility to use the inertia tensor to express the Kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

$$T=\frac{1}{2} \mathscr M \omega^2$$
Well in this situation the particle is in rotation.

Can we express  $T$ using the inertia tensor $I_{ij}$

Comment: Are you fine with starting with $T=\frac12\boldsymbol\omega\cdot\mathbf L$? If so, it pretty much falls right out from there.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but that's okay, anything may help me.

Comment: I have an answer typed out, but it is really just a bunch of calculations, which I don't really like. It makes this seem like an off-topic homework-like question... What have you tried so far? What physics concepts are particularly tripping you up here?

Comment: It's pretty clear to me, he's searching for a mathematical proof to express $T$ using inertia tensor, what's wrong with this question ?

Comment: @MohamedELF I didn't say it is an unclear question. It reads like an off-topic homework-like question because it just asks for a derivation/expression. It doesn't ask to understand any underlying physics concepts.

Comment: Sorry, it's just another communication issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a homework-like question (under our definition) to me, but it does seem like a question that doesn't show the level of effort we like to have on this site. Guntër me, would you consider editing the question to summarize what you tried? Any websites you checked or calculations you attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your question more clear,

I'm answering you, but I'm not sure, because I didn't understand your question well.

Let us Express $\mathscr M$ first in function of $\mathbf r$ the vector ray, note that :
$$\mathbf r^2=x_k x_k$$ Where $k=1,2,3\dots $ the composants of $\mathbf r$

and let considered an axis $D$ characterized by its vector $\mathbf u$ where $\mathbf r .\mathbf u =x_k u_k$ , therefore, we can write the moment of inertia : 
$$\mathscr M=m.d=m\bigl(x_k x_k-(x_k u_k)^2\bigr)$$
Thus:
$$\mathscr M=m \bigl(\mathbf r^2-(\mathbf r .\mathbf u)^2\bigr)$$ 
Now, working on the kinetic energy, we'll have $T=\frac{1}{2}m\mathbf v^2=\frac{1}{2}m(\boldsymbol{ \omega} \times \mathbf r)^2$

Using scalar product identities :
$$T=\frac{1}{2}m\boldsymbol{ \omega} (\mathbf r \times \boldsymbol{ \omega} \times \mathbf r)=\frac{1}{2}m\bigl(\mathbf r^2\boldsymbol{ \omega}^2-(\mathbf r .\boldsymbol{\omega} )^2\bigr)$$
The vector $\boldsymbol{ \omega}$ can be written (let $\omega$ be its module) :
$$\boldsymbol{ \omega_0}=\frac{\boldsymbol{ \omega}}{\omega}$$
Thus:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}m \omega\bigl(\mathbf r^2-(\mathbf r .\boldsymbol{ \omega_0})^2\bigr)$$
and here's $\mathscr M$ is obvious, so we can write the kinetic energy as:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\mathscr M \omega^2$$
**One more important identity :** 
$$\fbox{$\mathscr M =u_i u_j I_{ij}$}$$
In this case we'll have :
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\mathscr M \omega^2=\frac{1}{2} I_{ij}\omega_{0i}\omega_{0j}\omega^2=\frac{1}{2}I_{ij}\omega_i \omega_j$$
Therefore our final answer is :
$$T=\frac{1}{2}I_{ij}\omega_i \omega_j$$
I hope it'll be helpful, good luck !